# How to parse the xml string in Windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Please how to read the following xml string.

```
 <NewDataset>
  <Table>
  <Id>1</Id>
  </Table>
 </NewDataset>
```

i need to get the id .please tell me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 phone supports most of C#, so you can use all the same methods for parsing XML as you would in any other C# code. Look up XmlDocument or XDocument.

Answer (score 3):

```
var id = Convert.ToInt32(XDocument.Parse(xml).Root.Element("id").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

[here is a full tutorial reference](http://www.kotancode.com/2010/07/30/wp7-webservices-xml/) for you. the C# code parses this XML:

```
string xmlData =
     @"<ServiceReply>
       <StockQuote symbol='IBM' price='32.50' quotetime='01/01/2010 12:21:00'/>
       <StockQuote symbol='MSFT' price='21.20' quotetime='01/01/2010 12:20:30' />
      </ServiceReply>
     ";
```

using this piece of code:

```
var quotes = from quote in dataDoc.Descendants("StockQuote")
     let stamp = DateTime.Parse(quote.Attribute("quotetime").Value)
     orderby stamp ascending
     select new StockQuote
     {
       Symbol = quote.Attribute("symbol").Value,
       Price = decimal.Parse(quote.Attribute("price").Value)
     };
```

Let us know if it works. hope that helps